# Regarding the tag "each"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

The tag [each](/questions/tagged/each) isn't documented. In my opinion it is too vague to be useful and doesn't match any expertise area.

[Most questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/each?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=30) are related to jQuery's `each` for which already exists [jquery-each](/questions/tagged/jquery-each) with only 52 questions. Some other ones are related to Ruby, Java, PHP, VB...

I think the [each](/questions/tagged/each) tag should be removed and replaced by more specific tags like [jquery-each](/questions/tagged/jquery-each).

What do more experienced SO users think ?

Comment: \*whistles\* Trooooohhhhgdooooohhhhrrrr...buddy, come here, by foot...we've got work to do! ... ... ... In case that didn't get clear, just burn the whole thing and forget about it.

Comment: Great, there are even questions tagged as "[tag:javascript] [tag:each]" that *clearly* ask about jQuery and don't mention it anywhere in the body or the tags.

Comment: If there is no objection (I'll wait for them until tomorrow) I'll work on the retagging but it's unlikely I'll do it alone for all 791 questions...

Comment: @dystroy: No, please don't. Mass retaggings should *only* be done via a diamond mod. Everything else just interrupts the sites too much (f.e. the frontpage).

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby OK. But how do we deal with the few exceptions ? We don't want Ruby questions to be tagged [jquery-each].

Comment: @dystroy: I'm still for burning that tag, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: A quick glance down the sidebar shows that the tag is basically noise.  It adds no value to the questions that use it.  While there are some questions that *could* be tagged `jquery-else`, it's probably not worth the effort.  **BURNINATE!**

Comment: Ok for sending them all burn in hell. Hum... where's the red button ?